# How to define a type with some optional specified properties along side some required specified ones in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I have the below object:

```
const colors: tColors = {
  dark: {
     main: {
       normal: '#022c43', dark30: '#011f2f', light30: '#4e6b7b', contrastColor: '#fff',
     },
     secound: {
       normal: '#053f5e', dark30: '#042c42', light30: '#add6de', contrastColor: '#fff',
     },
     error: { normal: '#d32f2f', contrastColor: '#fff' },
     success: { normal: '#388e3c', contrastColor: '#fff' },
  },
  light: {
     main: {
       normal: '#28527a', dark30: '#1c3955', light30: '#6986a2', contrastColor: '#fff',
     },
     secound: {
       normal: '#8AC4D0', dark30: '#618992', light30: '#50798e', contrastColor: '#fff',
     },
     error: { normal: '#e57373', contrastColor: '#000' },
     success: { normal: '#81c784', contrastColor: '#000' },
  },
};
```

I define `tColors` like:

```
type tColors = {
  [themeKey in 'light' | 'dark']: {
    [key : string]: {
       [shadeKey: string ]: string
    }
  }
};
```

it works but if I want to limit the `shadeKey` like this:

```
shadekey in 'normal' | 'dark30' | 'light30' | 'contrastColor'
```

it gives me some errors on `error` and `success` fields, the errors are:

```
Type '{ normal: string; contrastColor: string; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ normal: string; dark30: string; light30: string; contrastColor: string; }': dark30, light30
```

the problem is I don't want to add `dark30` or `light30` in `error` and `success` fields but I want the `shadekey` to be sensitive about other keys

Is there any way that I can set the `dark30` and `light30` as optional properties, but the rest of them stay the same?

Comment: Just make it optional then: `[shadeKey in 'normal' | 'dark30' | 'light30' | 'contrastColor']?: string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `shadeKey` values are known and limited, you can write them as properties instead of index signatures:

```js
type tColors = {
  [themeKey in "light" | "dark"]: {
    [key: string]: {
      normal: string;
      dark30?: string;
      light30?: string;
      contrastColor: string;
    };
  };
};
```

Here `?` after `dark30` and `light30` suggests that the property is optional.